# Delete Embed Message with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Alright so heres my issue. I'm trying to delete a message that only contains an embed. However, the message wont delete. Here is what I've tried:

```
const embedMsg = message.embeds.find(msg => msg.title == 'Castle League Mafia');
if(embedMsg) {
  message.delete();
  return;
}
```

And I've just tried `message.delete()` once `players` is equal to 1 and that doesn't work either. It deletes my message (the one with the command for sending the embed)

Here is the place where I'm trying to do it: https://pastebin.com/DbuFx8Gs

Heres my full code: https://pastebin.com/6EJVTBFJ

Comment: Be careful with listeners inside listeners. You seem to be running `.on('messageReactionAdd', ...` every time the bot receives a message, which may cause problems. Use a reaction collector instead, as explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57452486/5831220).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code here

```js
// when you send the embed 
const embed = message.channel.send(Embed)

// if (blah blah blah) 
if (1 == 1) { // for testing
     embed.delete()
}
```

in your case this should work

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new discord.Client();

const prefix = '!'
const footer = "Mafia Bot V1.0 - Spoon";

var players = 0;

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Bot is logged in!");
    client.user.setActivity('Mafia', {type: 'PLAYING'}).then(presence => console.log(`Activity set to ${presence.activities[0].name}`)).catch(console.error);
});

client.on('message', message => {
    
    // Start Command
  var embedMsg;
    if (message.content === prefix + "newgame") {
        let newEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Castle League Mafia")
        .setDescription("**Everything here is going to be changed**\nReact to this message to join the mafia game!\n\n6 players in total are needed to play.\n\nIf you are the mafia, you will recieve a DM. If you do not recieve a DM, you are innocent.\n\n**" + players + "/6 Players**")
        .setColor("PURPLE")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(footer);
        embedMsg = message.channel.send(newEmbed);
    }

    // Add join reaction
    if(message.author.bot) {
        if(message.embeds) {
            if(embedMsg) {
                message.react('☑️');
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // When players react
    client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {

        if(reaction.emoji.name === "☑️"  && !user.bot) {
            players += 1;
            // When players join
            switch (players) {
                case 1:
                    console.log(players + " players are ready to play!");

                    if(embedMsg) {
                        embedMsg.delete();
                        return;
                    }

                    let startEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("Game has started!")
                    .setDescription("**Mafia has been messaged!**")
                    .setColor("PURPLE")
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setFooter(footer);
                    message.channel.send(startEmbed);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    console.log(players + " players are ready to play!");
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    console.log(players + " players are ready to play!");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return;
        }
    });

    client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
        
        
        if(reaction.emoji.name === "") {

        }
    });

    client.on("messageReactionRemove", (reaction, user) => {

        if(reaction.emoji.name === "☑️"  && !user.bot) {
            players -= 1;
            console.log(players + " players are ready to play!");
            return;
        }
    })

    

});
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for trying to help. I just tried your suggestions and I get the error: `TypeError: embedMsg.delete is not a function`. I didn't get the error before I changed the code