# I'm making a command, and i want to put one "more info button" with a reaction in discordjs

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, command

see, in the end of my command, I have this:

```
const awnserEmb = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
            (awnserEmb).react('❓')

        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return (
                ['❓'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id);
        };

        awnserEmb
            .awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
            .then((collected) => {
                const reaction = collected.first();

                if(reaction.emoji.name === '❓'){
                    message.channel.send('Mais informação')
                }
            })
            .catch((collected) => {
                message.channel.send('nada aconteceu');
            });
```

but doesn't work! says that awaitReactions is not a function!

Comment: It's because `answerEmb` is a promise. Add `await` before `message.channel.send` to resolve it first.

Comment: doesn't worked. T-T

Comment: Can you update your post with the updated code w/ `await`?

Comment: @GettyLowPepe What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it still say `awaitReactions is not a function`?

Comment: yes, Zsolt. I will update the post to the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Reactions for the use you want are deprecated in v13 unless you have privileged intents turned on

So I recommend the following

You can try the new [Interactive Buttons](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#building-and-sending-buttons) or [Menus](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/select-menus.html#building-and-sending-select-menus)

If you don't want to update to v13 (you will have to)
Use a [Reaction Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57452056/discord-js-how-to-send-a-message-and-collect-reactions-from-it)